# Все ближе к ответу 2 select option из Mysql. Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

2 зависимых списка.

Почти дошел до ответа путем множества дней проб и ошибок и хейта со стороны некоторых пользователей SO, но до сих пор не вижу где ошибка.

2 таблицы.

**Таблица mark** и поля `id`, `title` (названия марок, например Audi).

**Таблица model** и поля `id`, `mark_id` (сопоставление с id из таблицы mark) и `title` (названия моделей например A7)

Все марки из БД выводятся, а вот список моделей не подгружается, select просто пишет "Нет моделей"

**Запрос к бд идет через RedBean php.**

```
$marks = R::findAll('mark', 'ORDER BY title ASC');
```

**Зависимый список.**

```
<form action="search" name="search"  method="POST" id="search" >
  


<select class="select2" name="mark" id="mark" required>
    <option value="0" disabled selected>Выберите марку</option>
    <?php if (isset($marks)): ?>
        <?php foreach ($marks as $mark): ?>
             <option value="<?=$mark['id']; ?>"><?=$mark['title']; ?></option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
     <?php endif; ?>
</select>




<select class="select2" name="model" id="model" required disabled>
   <option value="0" disabled selected>Модель</option>  
</select>

  

</form>
```

**Ajax.**

```
<script>
   function getModel(parent, mark, model, create=0) {
        $(parent).on('change',mark, function () {
            var mark_id = $(mark).val();
            $.ajax({
              url: 'fetch_data.php',
                data: {
                    mark_id: mark_id,
                    create: create,
                },

                type: 'POST',
              method: 'POST',
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function (res) {
                    if (res) {
                        $(model).empty().html(res);
                    } else {
                        $(model).empty().html('<option>Нет моделей</option>');
                    }
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('Ошибка');
                }
            });
        });
    }


     /* Получение моделей авто в быстром поиске */
    getModel('#search', '#mark', '#model');



</script>
```

**fetch_data.php**

```
if ($_POST['mark']) {
    

$model = R::getAssoc('SELECT model.id, model.title AS model,mark.title AS mark
 FROM model
   INNER JOIN mark
    ON model.mark_id = mark.id');

    print json_encode($model);
}
```

**print_r($model);**

Выводит массив связанных марок-моделей. Почему он до сих пор не вносит их в select не понимаю...

Вот вид вывода массива.

```
[1] => Array
        (
            [model] => CL
            [mark] => Acura
        )

[2] => Array
        (
            [model] => EL
            [mark] => Acura
        )

[3] => Array
        (
            [model] => Integra
            [mark] => Acura
        )
```

Резюмируя вопрос, список марок загружается из Базы данных в select, а вот модели нет.

Коллеги, помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: а модели с маркой-то вы не хотите связать? вы аяксе выводите json и пытаетесь его запихать как html, ничего в этом вас не смущает?

Comment: @teran   подскажите пожалуйста, как это заменить???

Comment: @teran почитайте вот это на всякий случай :)
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1193593/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7-2-%D1%85-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86/1193667

Comment: @delikates  тот кто не смог дать даже намека на ответ, теперь еще что-то пишет, умно)) Видно у вас много свободного времени, чтобы отыскивать мои вопросы.

Comment: @Vovvka никто Вас и не искал. Не нужно создавать дублей. Почитайте правила на это счет.

Answer (score 0):

надеюсь, что за это время автор уже нашел решение. но если нет, то как минимум передаются одни поля, а проверяется совсем другое. или я не заметил код, где это преобразуется. то есть изначально нет шансов получить правильный ответ.
отправляются `mark_id` и `create` принимается `mark`

```
$.ajax({
              url: 'fetch_data.php',
                data: {
                    mark_id: mark_id,
                    create: create,
                },

if ($_POST['mark'])
```

так же не заметил что в запрос передается переменная для выбора нужных строк. в таком запросе должно отдавать содержимое всей таблицы.
для автора и всех начинающих, которые сталкиваются с подобными проблемами и найдут этот вопрос небольшое отступление от прямого ответа на вопрос.
для разделения проблемы полезно просто в браузере в инструментах разработчика посмотреть что и куда отдает клиентская часть и так же сделать переход по предполагаемоиму адресу php функции и увидеть что вообще отдается. там же можно заменить запрос с GET на POST и подставляя свои данные, имитировать работу AJAX, передавая предполагаемые данные. таким образом будут протестированы обе составляющие процесса и видно их взаимодействие.